# How to not recompile all files when building Go package and changed just one file?

Tags: go, compilation

In C for instance, files that were not modified since the last build are not rebuilt because their .o file is there already.

Is there something similar in Go ? I waste a lot of time rebuilding everything when I just made modifications to one file.

Comment: This is what `go install` does.

Comment: @JimB I have tried it but it didnt change anything

Comment: Then you need to show exactly what you are doing. Is this during `go test`? Are you editing the package being built, or a dependency? What packages does `go install -v` show are being built?